# Using for loops to create a christmas tree

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program where you enter a number and the program creates a "christmastree" arrangement of +'s. For example if I enter the number 5 the program should print:

```
    +
   +++
  +++++
 +++++++
+++++++++
```

What I have so far is:

```
def holidaybush(n):
    z=n-1
    x=1
    for i in range(0,n):
        for i in range(0,z):
            print('',end='')
        for i in range(0,x):
            print('+',end='')
        for i in range(0,z):
            print('',end='')
        x=x*2
        x=x-1
        z=z-1
        print()
holidaybush(5)
```

It does not work quite the way I expect, even though I go through the logic and it seems to work in my head. Any help? I just learned for loops today so I may not know everything about them.

Comment: What language? What *do* you get?

Comment: This looks like some invalid JS . . .

Comment: @Godisgood Nope, looks strongly like python3, so I've retagged it, once it gets though review...

Comment: @mastjoyce.  Yep, I think you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you have two problems. First, when you go to do your indentation, you write:

```
print('',end='')
```

In python (and other languages), `''` is an empty string. You should use `' '`.

Second, your `x` incrementing logic seems to be wrong. Simply adding `2` each loop works fine, making your program:

```
def holidaybush(n):
    z=n-1
    x=1
    for i in range(0,n):
        for i in range(0,z):
            print(' ',end='')
        for i in range(0,x):
            print('+',end='')
        for i in range(0,z):
            print(' ',end='')
        x=x+2
        z=z-1
        print()
holidaybush(5)
```

Your code can be made more compact by:

- Using infix operators, replacing `x=x+2` with `x+=2`
- `range` automatically starts at zero, so `range(0,z)` can be replaced with `range(z)`
- Using string multiplication, replacing your inner `for` loops with `' ' * z`

Applying these results in:

```
def holidaybush(n):
    z = n - 1
    x = 1
    for i in range(n):
        print(' ' * z + '+' * x + ' ' * z)
        x+=2
        z-=1
holidaybush(5)
```

But you might want to stick with the verbose version.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The trick with this program is that I am not allowed to multiply strings, because that makes it too easy. Missing the space was obviously stupid. Thanks for your help on making it tighter. I hadn't learned those shortcuts. It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could use `string.center()`, just for adding another solution, this made the code more compact:

```
def holidaybush(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(("+" * (i * 2 + 1)).center(n * 2 - 1))

holidaybush(5)
```

Answer (score 3):

how about this:

```
def holidaybush(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print ' ' * (n - (i + 1)),'+' * (2*i+1)

holidaybush(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the very simplest code to draw Christmas tree:

```
for i in range(1,20,2):
    print(('*'*i).center(20))

for leg in range(3):
    print(('||').center(20))

print(('\====/').center(20))
```

Answer (score 1):

My one line solution.

```
def holiday_bush(x):
    print("\n".join([f"{'+'*(2* n + 1):^{2*x+1}}" for n in range(x)]))
```

Result:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

If you want also a trunk on the base:

```
def holiday_bush(x):
    print("\n".join([f"{'+'*(2* n + 1):^{2*x+1}}" for n in (*range(x), 0, 0)]))
```

Result:

```
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
    *    
    *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the 'x+=2' to 'x+=1' you get the right shape, but not as many '+', but it won't be as wide
mod:

```
def holidaybush(n):
z = n 
x =1

for i in range(n):
    print(' ' * z + '+' * x + ' ' * z)
    x+=1
    z-=1


holidaybush(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it without any numbers, just for fun

```
n = int(input("how big?\t"))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n-i):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('\b', end='') #cheating
    for k in range(i+n-j):
        print('*', end='')
    print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number = -1
Range = int(input("how many layers do you want the tree?"))
for x in range(0,Range):
    number = number + 2
    print(" " * (Range - x), "+" * number)
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
a=7
n=7
for i in range(7):
  print(" "*a,end="")
  print("*"*(2*i+1))
  a-=1
for b in range (n//2):
  print("     *****")
```

`
try this simple code to print the tree using for loop

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    size = int(input("Enter the number of rows for the tree:"))
    last_row = (2 * size) - 1
    for i in range(1, size + 1):
        print(((" ") * (size - i)) + (("*") * ((2 * i) - 1)))
```

I came up with this code for the tree program.

Comment: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -2):

```
height = eval(input("Enter height of tree: "))
for row in range(height):
    for count in range(height - row):
        print(end=" ")
    for count in range(2*row + 1):
        print(end="*")
    print()
```

Comment: Please provide description at least  what you want to ask

Comment: please format your code and add description why you think the code block should be used