# Drawing an "X" pattern in Python using only nested for loops and if/else statement

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to write a program that will display the pattern shown in the linked picture for any number of odd rows specified by the user.

[image]

The user will input the number of rows they wish for the pattern to display (it must be an odd number).

Restrictions:

The program MUST be implemented using only nested for loops and if/else statements. Luckily, I've been able to glean that the solution certainly involves a nested for loop for each individual half of the pattern (i.e. top and bottom half), and that the if/else statement will need to be inside the inner for loop.

I have spent about 9 hours troubleshooting this and messing around with different organizations of the code. Every version that I've tried has failed, and I haven't even been able to create similar patterns.

Any and all help is inexpressibly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26555986/using-for-loops-to-create-a-christmas-tree  it is not excactly a duplicate, but it's close

Comment: Oh wow! That's ganna help me a lot! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Phoenix. Note that I didn't edit your post solely to remove the 'Help appreciated'; The main purpose was to insert the image. See this meta post on why I did remove the last line though: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts